# Exoplayer PlayerNotificationManager onSwipe

Tags: java, android, exoplayer2.x

I'm using Exoplayer version 2.11.0 and I wonder if there is possibility of stoping PlayerNotificationManager when user swipes it to the right (analogically to Spotify). By default I can only call useStopAction(true) https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerNotificationManager.html 
which doesn't satisfy me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
   @Override
                public void onNotificationPosted(int notificationId, Notification notification, boolean ongoing) {
                    if (ongoing) {
                        // Make sure the service will not get destroyed while playing media.
                        startForeground(notificationId, notification);
                    } else {
                        // Make notification cancellable.
                        stopForeground(false);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be much improved by adding some explanation of why the code works and where it should be used.

Comment: This code will dismiss PlayerNotification whether user pause the song. I don't think that should be the best approach

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Ibrahim Ali Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61236223/10284292) we can make notification to dismiss onSwipe when exoplayer is not playing.

```
  @Override
  public void onNotificationPosted(int notificationId, Notification notification, boolean ongoing) {
      if (ongoing) {
          // Here Audio is playing, so we need to make sure the service will not get destroyed by calling startForeground.
          startForeground(notificationId, notification);
      } else {
          //Here audio has stopped playing, so we can make notification dismissible on swipe.
          stopForeground(false);
      }
  }
```

`onNotificationPosted` is called each time after the notification is update by exoplayer. here [onGoing](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/59b34ede6165d029d86a677fea73a5dd0dd55c74/library/ui/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/PlayerNotificationManager.java#L1220) is true when player is playing any audio. So we can decide on onGoing whether notification should be dismissible or not.

```
    /** Returns whether the generated notification should be ongoing. */
      protected boolean getOngoing(Player player) {
        int playbackState = player.getPlaybackState();
        return (playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING || playbackState == Player.STATE_READY) && player.getPlayWhenReady();
  }
```